# Devise Sign Up function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, devise, rubygems

How do I make devise execute functions after sign up, sign in etc. I tried putting functions like this in my application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    execute stuff
  end
end
```

With my routes like this

```
devise_for :users do
     get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried making an sessions controller like so

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    functions
end
```

With my routes like this

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions'} do
    get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

This doesn't seem to do anything as well, is there something I'm missing in making devise responsive. (I initially set up devise using this tutorial)
https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-(Walkthrough)

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you're trying to do and how it's failing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own `sessions_controller` which inherits from `Devise::SessionsController` and override the actions you'd like to customize. For example, to perform some action after a user signs in, you could do:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
    perform_custom_stuff
  end
end
```

If calling `super` is insufficient, you could reproduce the current implementation of `Devise::SessionsController#create` in your controller. Then you have full control over what's happening and can customize to tailor your exact needs. This may not be the prettiest solution, but might be necessary (at least to keep you going).

Comment: I tried that, it is unresponsive to my custom stuff, like if i say redirect_to 'www.google.ca' , it won't do that (as well as other stuff)

Comment: specifically I want to do render json: resource_name.to_json, :callback => params[:callback] , to get a JSONP array on sign up. The way it's failing is that it just won't do anything at all on sign-in or sign-up whenever i put anything to modify sessions (it just signs in and goes to the main page, and behaves as if i made no modification)

Comment: Kevin in your routes you are telling devise to use its sessions controller and not yours. Follow @Mike Mazur 's advice changing your routes and it should work like a champ.

Comment: @janders223 I'm not sure what exactly should i change in my routes though, if it's :sessions => 'devise/sessions' , theni already tried it as :sessions => 'sessions' , which throws an error (template missing) , so i think that is just specifying views (so where should I change it and how)

Comment: You get the template error because it is no longer looking for the devise page but yours. Try copying the view from devise to your sessions view folder and change your route back.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that `after_sign_up_path_for` and similar methods are only intended to return a path. I don't think it is a good idea to rely on those kind of methods for side effects.